# mkfs.xfs on EBS volume as non-root user on AWS

Tags: virtualization, amazon-web-services, xen

I've set up a udev rule to attach a particular EBS volume as owned by a user, and this works. Here are the permissions on the device node after the volume has been attached:

```
brw-rw---- 1 myuser myuser 202, 240 Feb  4 20:21 /dev/xvdp
```

But when I try to run `mkfs -t xfs /dev/xvdp` I get the error:

```
mkfs.xfs: error - cannot set blocksize 512 on block device /dev/xvdp: Permission denied
```

If I run the command as root it succeeds OK, and if I change the filesystem type to ext4 the operation also succeeds.

What extra permission to I need to give the device so my user can format it without `sudo`ing? Or is this likely a Xen or xfs bug?

I'm running amazon linux:

    <sub><sub>`Linux version 3.2.36-1.46.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31003) (gcc version 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-2) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Jan 14 04:42:23 UTC 2013`</sub></sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ioctl(... ,BLKBSZSET, ...)
```

requires root permissions.

You might try

```
mkfs -t xfs -s size=`blockdev --getbsz /dev/xvdp` /dev/xvdp
```

and see if not requiring a different blocksize will bypass the operation.